# Assign groups based on variables

Tags: sas

In SAS, I have a dataset(have) as below, I need to add a group variable based on test and visitnum. When visitnum is 101 and 108, they need to be in the same group. The desired as shown as data want.

data have:

```
test visitnum ord seq
aa    101      0   0 
aa    101      0   1 
aa    108      1   0 
aa    108      1   1 
aa    108      2   0 
aa    108      2   1
aa    115      1   0 
aa    115      1   1 
aa    115      2   0 
aa    115      2   1 
bb    101      0   0 
bb    101      0   1 
bb    108      1   0 
bb    108      1   1 
bb    108      2   0 
bb    108      2   1
bb    115      1   0 
bb    115      1   1 
bb    115      2   0 
bb    115      2   1
```

data want:

```
test visitnum ord seq group
aa    101      0   0    1
aa    101      0   1    1
aa    108      1   0    1
aa    108      1   1    1
aa    108      2   0    1
aa    108      2   1    1
aa    115      1   0    2
aa    115      1   1    2
aa    115      2   0    2
aa    115      2   1    2
bb    101      0   0    3
bb    101      0   1    3
bb    108      1   0    3
bb    108      1   1    3
bb    108      2   0    3
bb    108      2   1    3
bb    115      1   0    4
bb    115      1   1    4
bb    115      2   0    4
bb    115      2   1    4
```

Comment: Are they ordered by test and visitnum? Should the order be conserved? Can visitnum be a number between 101 and 108? Please edit your question.

Comment: Yes, they are ordered by test and visitnum. After creating the group, the order should be by test, group, and visitnum. There won't be other number between 101 and 108.

Answer (score 0):

First sort your data by `test` and `visitnum`. There are two cases when we want to increment the group number:

1. When it's the start of a `test` group and the visitnum is 101 or 108
2. When it's the start of a `visitnum` group and it's not 101 or 108

Here's how this looks:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by test visitnum;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by test visitnum;

    if(   first.test AND visitnum IN(101, 108) 
       OR (first.visitnum AND visitnum NOT IN(101, 108) )
      ) 
    then group+1;
run;
```

Output:

```
test    visitnum    ord seq group
aa      101        0    0   1
aa      101        0    1   1
aa      108        1    0   1
aa      108        1    1   1
aa      108        2    0   1
aa      108        2    1   1
aa      115        1    0   2
aa      115        1    1   2
aa      115        2    0   2
..      ...        ..   ..  ..
bb      115        2    0   4
bb      115        2    1   4
```